# Selecting the first row of a sorted group from pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, group-by

Suppose, I have a dataframe in pandas like below:

```
campaignname    category_type    amount
A               cat_A_0            2.0
A               cat_A_1            1.0
A               cat_A_2            3.0
A               cat_A_2            3.0
A               cat_A_2            4.0
B               cat_B_0            3.0
C               cat_C_0            1.0
C               cat_C_1            2.0
```

I am using the following code to group the above dataframe (say it's assigned variable name `df`) by different columns as follows:

```
for name, gp in df.groupby('campaignname'):
    sorted_gp = gp.groupby(['campaignname', 'category_type']).sum().sort_values(['amount'], ascending=False)
    # I'd like to know how to select this in a cleaner/more concise way
    first_row = [sorted_gp.iloc[0].name[0], sorted_gp.iloc[0].name[1], sorted_gp.iloc[0].values.tolist()[0]]
```

The purpose of the above code is to first `groupby` the raw data on `campaignname` column, then in each of the resulting group, I'd like to group again by both `campaignname` and `category_type`, and finally, sort by `amount` column to choose the first row that comes up (the one with the highest `amount` in each group. Specifically for the above example, I'd like to get results like this:

```
first_row = ['A', 'cat_A_2', 4.0] # for the first group
first_row = ['B', 'cat_B_0', 3.0] # for the second group
first_row = ['C', 'cat_C_1', 2.0] # for the third group
```

etc.

As you can see, I'm using a rather (in my opinion) 'ugly' way to **retrieve the first row of each sorted group**, but since I'm new to pandas, I don't know a better/cleaner way to accomplish this. If anyone could let me know a way to select the first row in a sorted group from a pandas dataframe, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you in advance for your answers/suggestions!

Answer (score 10):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
In [83]: df.groupby('campaignname', as_index=False) \
           .apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(1, columns=['amount'])) \
           .reset_index(level=1, drop=1)
Out[83]:
  campaignname category_type  amount
0            A       cat_A_2     4.0
1            B       cat_B_0     3.0
2            C       cat_C_1     2.0
```

or:

```
In [76]: df.sort_values('amount', ascending=False).groupby('campaignname').head(1)
Out[76]:
  campaignname category_type  amount
4            A       cat_A_2     4.0
5            B       cat_B_0     3.0
7            C       cat_C_1     2.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But when I run the code you suggested, it still returns the whole dataframe, but grouped-by and sorted. What I'd like is to iterate over the groups, sort within each group based on amount, select **only the top row of the sorted result in each group iteratively**. I guess my question is too vague and maybe I should modify it...

Comment: If there are multiple maximum values of ```amount```, is it possible to take an average over them? More generally, if in this problem I have an extra column ```x``` and I want to select values of ```x``` from the row with the largest ```amount```, grouped by ```campaignname```, how do I do it while using average in the case of multiple maximum values?

Answer (score 4):

My preferred way to do this is with `idxmax`.  It returns the index of the maximum value.  I subsequently use that index to slice `df`

```
df.loc[df.groupby('campaignname').amount.idxmax()]

  campaignname category_type  amount
4            A       cat_A_2     4.0
5            B       cat_B_0     3.0
7            C       cat_C_1     2.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But when I run the code you suggested, it still returns the whole dataframe, but grouped-by and sorted. What I'd like is to iterate over the groups, sort within each group based on `amount`, select the top row of the sorted result. I guess my question is too vague and maybe I should modify it...

Comment: @user1330974 this should return the same thing you asked for.  The first row after having sorted within each group.  What I've posted shows what you would get, which is what you asked for.

Comment: after running the `df.loc[df.groupby('campaignname').amount.idxmax()]`, I still see all rows in the data frame... Thank you for your help!